# Multiple modal dialog scroll bar Bootstrap v.3.3.5 not working well

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I created multiple `modal dialog` with bootstrap v.3.3.5. when I launched the first `modal dialog`, the scrollbar in the right working well but after I launch the second `modal dialog`, and close it, the scrollbar disappears.

In bootstrap v.3.0.0 there isn't any problem as you can see in below demo

[modal dialog with bootstrap v.3.0.0](http://www.bootply.com/KCfW2ielTb)

But, in bootstrap v.3.3.5 there problem exists

[modal dialog with bootstrap v.3.3.5](http://www.bootply.com/vF6k98wThg)

Comment: So in `3.0.0` version its working right?

Comment: yes for scroll bar, check my example please

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/LqnYKE4Rgk)**

For some reason it is removing my `modal-open` class from body and this scrollbar disappears. So here is a neat trick to capture the close event of `.modal` and check if any `.modal` is open and if yes add the `.modal-open` class to `body`

```
$("#myModal2").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
  if ($('.modal:visible').length) //check if any modal is open
  {
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');//add class to body
  }
});
```

Now if you have multiple modals nesting inside each other, just replace `$("#myModal2")` with `$(document)`

**UPDATE**

Lately I came to know that this can be done with pure CSS with just a line as below:

```
.modal{
   overflow:auto !important;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/iPnFXDfEld)**

Comment: The CSS fix worked for me.  I can attest that this is still a problem in Bootstrap 3.3.7.  Thanks for the easy fix.

Comment: The CSS fix seems to create an additional scrollbar, whereas the JS doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

> Dynamically added modals

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    if ($('body').find('.modal.in').length > 0) {
        $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    }
});
```

> Update for **Bootstrap 4**

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    if ($('body').find('.modal.show').length > 0) {
        $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing,
just add following to your CSS :

```
#myModal{
 overflow:auto !important;
}
```

Hope it helps !!